# Netbeans 7.1.2 not available after installation in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, java, ide, netbeans

I have upgraded to ubuntu 12.04.

I downloaded netbeans from the netbeans site with a .sh file. Followed the instructions 
`chmode +x <filename.sh> ..`  no response. It required me to update JDK and JRE. Yet I am not able to find the netbeans IDE application. Am I **missing** something ?  Please help.  Setting a foot into netbeans from eclipse but almost stuck.

Comment: personal preference, stick with eclipse.  it's more standard and more mature.  if there's a particular plugin available for netbeans that isn't available for eclipse post a separate question on that and i'll see what i can do

Comment: i want to help this guy, but netbeans is imo an eclipse clone that fails at everything except RAD for java guis...i need a finer point on what he's trying to accomplish -- quote of me from chat

Comment: What is the error msg when you execute the shellscript, i.e., what happens when you run `./<filename.sh>` in bash?

Answer (score 2):

Copy the `.sh` file to the home directory and  in terminal enter

```
chmod +x netbeans-blabalbla.sh
```

After that  go to the `netbeans` file in home directory and double click and select *run in terminal*. This procedure worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After you have made the installer executable (`chmod +x netbeans-blabalbla.sh`) you need to run it. Otherwise netbeans won't be installed. The command you have issued only makes the installer runnable. You can also install netbeans via `sudo apt-get install netbeans` but then you get an older version.